# Why isn't my regex matching my input data?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a column of values (strings) that look like this:

```
arg123ala
arg345ala_r
thr567por thr789pro
pro1ala,thr2leu
```

I am trying to identify those values where the following pattern is met only once and no extra text is present:

```
three letters-some numbers-three letters
```

In the previous example, this would match the first value, but not the other three, because they have extra bits of text or there are two instances of the pattern separated by blank spaces or commas.

I tried using something like this in Perl:

```
if ( $value =~ /^[[:alpha:]]{3}\d{1,9}[[:alpha:]]{3}$) {
    $qualifier = "ok";
}
else {
    $qualifier = "needs cleaning";
}
```

And actually checked the regular expression in regexplanet.com, where it worked beautifully. However, when I used it in my code it wasn't matching any of the values I listed above, missing even the first one. Any idea why this could be happening? Any advice on an alternative for this?

Comment: How are you reading in the data?  Have you printed them with <> around the value to look for white space at the beginning/end?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You don't need to apologize for poor formatting, your post is *vastly* better than most first posts on the site. I made some edits, but they're just minor things.

Comment: [Works for me](http://codepad.org/NNCY5LGf).

Comment: Also, are you sure "some" < 10?

Comment: What error did you get when you ran the perl code ?

Comment: You need to copy and paste the code that *doesn't* work. There's nothing we can tell from code that *does*

Answer (score 5):

It works fine. Here it is fixed (you didn't terminate your regex) and incorporated into a working program

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

while ( my $value = <DATA> ) {

  my $qualifier;

  if ( $value =~ /^[[:alpha:]]{3}\d{1,9}[[:alpha:]]{3}$/ ) {

      $qualifier = "ok";
  }
  else {
      $qualifier = "needs cleaning";
  }

  say $qualifier;
}

__DATA__
arg123ala
arg345ala_r
thr567por thr789pro
pro1ala,thr2leu
```

#### output

```
ok
needs cleaning
needs cleaning
needs cleaning
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like topic starter forgot final / in regexp.
I would use expression like this: /^[a-z]{3}\d+[a-z]{3}$/